# Can't yum WINE from repo - No package wine available

Tags: centos, yum, wine

I'm trying to install WINE on Centos 5.10 as per some instructions I wrote last year using this instruction:

```
# yum install wine
```

However when run, it can't find any package under that name:

```
# yum install wine
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.mhd.uk.as44574.net
 * extras: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
 * updates: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
Setting up Install Process
No package wine available.
Nothing to do
```

I tried saving the RPMs from the Centos 5.10 livecd locally and using them as a repo but it's not found there either.

How can I install WINE via yum without having to resort to RPMs?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into adding the EPEL repository to your RHEL build. EPEL is Fedora packages built against RHEL http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL I have not used this repo to install wine but do currently have it installed in my Scientific Linux 6 RHEL clone.
If you are not familiar with install 3rd party repositories then you may want to have a peek at the centos documentation here: http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories. I also use Atrpms but that is probably overkill for your requirements.